# How traefik route Host:{containerName}.{domain} to container in kubernetes provider like docker

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

From the demo from [traefik image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik/),it can route Host:{containerName}.{domain} to container by default like this:
[image: snapshot]
Can traefik do this in k8s provider?

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be solved by Traefik Template.

[Kubernetes Ingress Config](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/):

```
# Override default configuration template.
#
# Optional
# Default: <built-in template>
#
# filename = "kubernetes.tmpl"
```

[Default Kubernetes Template](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/templates/kubernetes.tmpl)

The template write by go template, then you can do everything in the template.